# In Jmeter is it possible to create a reusable object at the start of test plan?

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter is it possible to create a reusable object at the start of test plan?

For example, could I instantiate a Groovy Sql.class object, and then have access to that class object for the rest of the suite?

If this is possible, I am looking for a basic idea of how I would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `props.put(String name, Object value)` method as follows:

In the first sampler:

```
Sql sql = new Sql();
props.put("sql", sql);
```

In the second sampler:

```
Sql sql = props.get("sql");
sql.invokeMethod();
```

JMeter Properties are global and once defined you'll be able to access object value anywhere in the test plan.

For more and better explanation on the domain refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide, the majority of pre-defined variables like "props", "ctx", "vars", etc. are the same for Beanshell and JSR223 / groovy

Answer (score 0):

For this you use Setup Thread Group:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group

It is equivalent of setUp in JUnit

Answer (score 0):

I was getting **BeanShellInterpreter ERROR... Class not found in namespace**. My workaround was to change its type to 'var' instead of 'Sql' (referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28146406/4386440).

Instead of

```
Sql sql = props.get("sql");
sql.invokeMethod();
```

I used

```
var sql = props.get("sql");
sql.invokeMethod();
```